# How to use SharedWorker in Angular?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, shared-worker

I already have Workers in my Angular app. But I'm trying to create a Shared Worker, and it fails, saying "Failed to fetch a worker script." in the console.

```
const worker = new SharedWorker('../../../workers/my.shared.worker', { name: 'mySharedWorker', type: 'module' });
```

If I replace SharedWorker with Worker - it works perfectly.

Of course, I made everything as needed. Created an additional `.tsconfig` file:

```
/// tsconfig.worker.json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/worker",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "webworker"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/workers/*.worker.ts"
  ]
}
```

And added `webWorkerTsConfig` to `angular.json` config:

```
projects.myProject.architect.build.options.webWorkerTsConfig: "tsconfig.worker.json"
```

I found [this article by Nikita Barsukov](https://medium.com/@nikita.s.barsukov/dedicated-and-shared-web-workers-in-angular-c3df473882f6) but it works only if your Worker is stored as a single file in the `assets` folder. But my SharedWorker contains dozen of .ts files, that should be bundled just like an ordinary Worker.

Answer (score 1):

Seems Angular-CLI now (as for v10.0.7) supports Workers only. But not SharedWorkers.

Angular-CLI uses [worker-plugin](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/worker-plugin) under the hood. And actually, it can load SharedWorkers, but it should be [enabled in WebpackConfig](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/worker-plugin#sharedworker-boolean).

So there are two options.

1. Use `@angular-builders/custom-webpack` and add `sharedWorker` parameter to `WorkerPlugin` in custom webpack config. But I was unable to make it work.
2. Use [custom-webpack loader](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/worker-plugin#loader) (this options works for me):

```
import workerUrl from 'worker-plugin/loader?name=mySharedWorker!../../../workers/my.shared.worker.ts';
// ....
const worker = new SharedWorker(workerUrl, { name: 'mySharedWorker', type: 'module' });
```

Where `name=mySharedWorker` is the name of future bundle file. If you omit it, it will use something like `0.worker.js`, but it can cause a collision with ordinary Worker bundling because it'll use the same name. So always specify the name of your bundle in loader params.

Comment: I want to use your option 2, but don't know what file to add your scriptlet to.

Comment: @Woodsman, in any file where you want to create SharedWorker. Just do not forget to import that file to your build. For example, I create it in angular service constructor for my case.